# Translate the schema provided in into an “equivalent” relational schema (tables) in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Person(p#,name,birthdate,nationality,gender)

Actor(p#,aguild#)
    FK (p#) refs Person

Director(p#,dguild#)
    FK (p#) refs Person

Writer(p#, wguild#)
    FK (p#) refs Person

Studio(name)

ScreenPlay(title,year)

Authored(title,year,writer)
    FK (title, year) refs ScreenPlay
    FK (writer) refs Writer (p#)

Movie(title,studio,year,genre,director,length)
    FK (studio) refs Studio (name)
    FK (title, year) refs ScreenPlay
    FK (director) refs Director (p#)

Cast(title,studio,year,role,actor,minutes)
    FK (title, studio, year) refs Movie
    FK (actor) refs Actor (p#)

Affiliated(director,studio)
    FK (director) refs Director (p#)
    FK (studio) refs Studio (name)

I am unable to make the table for the author, I get an error saying "does not conform to the description 
of the parent key of table or nickname"

```
CREATE TABLE person (
p# int,
name varchar(255),
birthdate DATE,
nationality varchar(255),
gender varchar(255), 
constraint person_pk
primary key (p#)
);

CREATE TABLE actor (
p# int,
aguild varchar(255),
constraint actor_pk    
primary key (p#),
constraint actor_fk_person
foreign key (p#) references person
);

CREATE TABLE director (
p# int,
dguild varchar(255),
constraint director_pk    
primary key (p#),
constraint director_fk_person
foreign key (p#) references person
);

CREATE TABLE writer (
p# int,
wguild varchar(255),
constraint writer_pk    
primary key (p#),
constraint writer_fk_person
foreign key (p#) references person
);

CREATE TABLE studio ( 
name varchar(255) not null,
constraint studio_pk    
primary key (name)
);

CREATE TABLE screenplay ( 
title varchar(255) not null,
year varchar(255) not null,
constraint screenplay_pk    
primary key (title, year)
);

CREATE TABLE authored ( 
title varchar(255) not null,
year varchar(255) not null,
writer varchar(255) not null,
constraint authored_pk
primary key (title,year,writer),
constraint authored_fk_titleyear
foreign key (title, year) references screenplay,
constraint authored_fk_writer
foreign key (writer) references writer (p#) on delete no action
);

CREATE TABLE movie (
title varchar(255) not null,
studio varchar(255) not null,
year varchar(255) not null,
genre varchar(255),
director varchar(255),
length varchar(255),
constraint movie_pk    
primary key (title, studio, year),
constraint movie_fk_studio
foreign key (studio) references studio(name),
constraint movie_fk_titleyear
foreign key (title, year) references screenplay,
constraint movie_director
foreign key (director) references director(p#)
);

CREATE TABLE cast (
title varchar(255) not null,
studio varchar(255) not null,
year varchar(255) not null,
role varchar(255) not null,
actor varchar(255) not null,
minutes varchar(255),
constraint cast_pk    
primary key (title, studio, year, role, actor),
constraint cast_fk_titlestudioyear
foreign key (title, studio, year) references movie,
constraint cast_fk_actor
foreign key (actor) references actor(p#)
);

CREATE TABLE affiliated (
director varchar(255) not null,
studio varchar(255) not null,
constraint affiliated_pk    
primary key (director, studio),
constraint affiliated_fk_director
foreign key (director) references director(p#)
constraint affiliated_fk_studio
foreign key (studio) references studio(name)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several elementary mistakes. You appear to be learning, so take the time to study basic rules of RDBMS and data modelling/normalisation.

It's unwise to use column names with special characters like # because it will give maintenance and usability issues. You are using "p#" to indicate a primary key that is a surrogate, but that is unwise, consider using a naming convention instead for column-names of surrogate key. For example : person_pk, actor_pk, director_pk, writer_pk.

Some of your tables use surrogate keys (p#) while others use natural keys(example studio.name). If you use natural-keys that are long (example varchar(255)), then child tables that use those natural-keys will use much more space and searches will be less efficient than if you use a surrogate key of type integer or bigint for the pk.

Next if you want a column to act as a primary key then it must be NOT NULL. some of your tables break this rule so will fail to create.

When you have a foreign key, its column(s) datatype(s) must match that of the relevant parent table column(s). Your example breaks that rule so you will get syntax errors.

authored_fk_writer needs to reference a key of writers but you have omitted any key field, and the relevant foreign key column is varchar(255) which does not correspond to the primary key of writer (which is int).

For some of your compound foreign keys that use natural-keys, the compound length exceeds documented limits. Consider normalising your model to use correct datatypes for the foreign key columns (i.e. don't duplicate the natural key in the child table, but instead use the surrogate key column of the parent table).

Answer (score 0):

The clause 'references writer ()' is not correct in DB2. You must either not specify any columns including parentheses (the parent table must have PK in this case), or specify the corresponding columns of the parent table explicitly inside the parentheses (the parent table must have PK or Unique Constraint on them).

Check the REFERENCES clause syntax of the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) statement.

Comment: how should I go about creating a table for this schema: Authored(title,year,writer) FK (title, year) refs ScreenPlay FK (writer) refs Writer (p#)

Comment: does it have anything to do with int and varchar types?

Comment: Please, don't write phrases like "it didn't work". If you faced some error returned by db2, provide exact SQLCODE and message text. All SQLCODEs are described in the documentation. You have 2 problems still: 1 You are not able to create PK on column allowing NULL values (as you showed for the 'writer' table), so I'm curious about how you did it. 2. The corresponding columns must be compatible in terms of data types, and this clearly stated in the description of SQL0538N you probably got attempting to create the 'authored' table.